# How do I average frequency spectra?

Tags: averaging

[image]

How did letter d.) become letter e.)? How do we perform this averaging process? Its clear the averaging the signal causes some noise to be reduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in a position to acquire $N$ snapshots of data, $s_n(t)$, for $n=0\ldots N-1$ then you can just do:

$$
S_n(k) = |\mathrm{fft}(s_n(t))|^2\\
\hat{S}(k) =  \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} S_n(k)
$$

and a certain amount of averaging will reduce the apparent noise on the spectrum.

Comment: this assumes the signal is "stationary", right?

Comment: Right: any time you're using the spectrum, you're assuming stationarity.  When you're averaging multiple spectra as here, you're assuming stationarity over a longer period.

Comment: Can you perhaps give some justification and details about the assumptions needed? Or point towards a source? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I ask because this seems to be applying Bartlett's method in a case where the original data is already non-contiguous.

Comment: @AdomasBaliuka Please [ask a new question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) if this answer doesn't help you. Feel free to reference this question and answer in your question, to set context for what you're asking.